# É possível passar a reputação da versão em Português para o StackOverflow original?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Este site não tem muitas perguntas nem respostas, pois queria migrar para o **StackOverflow** original (o que ta em Inglês), seria isso possível?

Comment: Mas justamente por termos menos perguntas e respostas é que sua contribuição é mais importante aqui do que lá... Sem dizer que lá a competição é bem mais feroz.

Comment: Justamente. Enquanto o SOen tem quase 10 milhões de perguntas, temos aqui no SOpt pouco mais de 20 mil. Por um lado, o site em Inglês tem mais conteúdo. Por outro lado, este site tem muito potencial a ser explorado, público alvo mais específico e oportunidade de crescimento dentro da comunidade.

Comment: Respondendo de forma simples: NÃO.

Comment: Outro detalhe, é muitas vezes mais fácil você tirar uma dúvida aqui do que lá, visto que aqui tem menos perguntas sendo feitas por hora, o que faz ganhar mais destaque e ter maior probabilidade de receber uma resposta de forma rápida.

Comment: Isso seria como uma "evasão de divisas".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O *https://stackoverflow.com* (também conhecido como **SOen**) é uma comunidade e o *https://pt.stackoverflow.com* (também conhecido como **SOpt**) é outra comunidade, assim como o https://superuser.com (também conhecido como **SU**) é outra comunidade.

Ou seja, nenhuma tem vínculo direto com a outra, são comunidades *primas* no máximo, então não tem sentido passar a reputação adquirida em um lugar para outro, **a reputação se refere** ao que você fez na comunidade específica.

Note que existem mais de 180 comunidades no [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) com assuntos diversificados e nem todos relacionados a informática (existe comunidades sobre idiomas, medicina, jurídico, etc), então como já dito, não é por que as comunidades *SOen* e *SOpt* são parecidas que elas a mesma coisa.

Sobre a pergunta:

> Este site não tem muitas perguntas nem respostas, pois queria migrar para o *Stack Overflow original* (o que ta em Inglês), seria isso possível?

Não tem como comparar, o *SOen*, que é uma comunidade mundial (e não só para países de língua inglesa) com o *SOpt*. Além deste fator, a época do lançamento de ambos tem uma diferença de praticamente 5 anos:

- *SOen* existe desde [2008](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/) (lançado em 15 de Setembro de 2008)
- *SOpt* existe desde Dezembro de 2013 (e o [beta público](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) foi lançado em 29 de Janeiro de 2014)

Em outras palavras, o número de perguntas e respostas é bem aceitável.

Comment: É, agora entendi. Obrigado...

Answer (score 8):

Se a sua área é pouco movimentada por aqui, você pode aproveitar deste fato para ser ativo em ambas comunidades.

Apesar de ter pequena experiência em outras linguagens, meu foco principal (e atual) é [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Infelizmente a média de perguntas no SOpt nesta tag é de apenas uma a cada 2~3 dias, e obviamente não sei responder todas, nem sou a única pessoa que acompanha a tag. Assim, gasto muito mais tempo no SOen, e além de responder, aprendo bastante por lá. O SOpt acaba ganhando por tabela: eventualmente o que eu aprendo lá pode ser útil para responder uma pergunta aqui.

Você só tem a ganhar participando das duas comunidades, não há porque escolher apenas uma! E o sistema do Stack Exchange ainda facilita nossa "vida dupla", já que as notificações aparecem independente da comunidade aberta no navegador.